# Confusion regarding android app development

Tags: android, android-layout

I was following an android development course and the instructor created an layout file named activity_youtube.xml and also gave the id to the layout as activity_youtube, later in the .java file the code he wrote was

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube)
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_youtube)`

I am really confused between this naming convention.

What are we refering to when we call `R.layout.activity_youtube` and what are we refering to when we call `R.id.activity_youtube`

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling *R.layout.activity_youtube* you are referring to the layout xml file, so to **everything** that's inside.
While when calling *R.id.activity_youtube* you are referring to a specific component inside that file (a layout, a Button, a textView... ) that has the *id* property assigned to that name.
I will admit that it might be a little misleading calling the layout. xml file and its layout component the same.

Comment: Thanks philoez98, got it.

Answer (score 1):

**`R`** is a public final class in Android which extends Object class. It is purely there as a mechanism to allow you to **easily reference the contents of your res hierarchy** from your code. As such, you cannot create sub-hierarchies.

**`R.id`** is a nested class file created in android programming its also auto-generated file. It is **used to refer to a UI component**. Let us suppose you have two buttons in your UI(R.laoyout.your_layout_name) you can distinguish them and decide which action to be performed on the click of each button by using `R.id.button1` and `R.id.button2`. These buttons lie in the layout file which you have used in the activity using `R.layout`.

`setContentView()` sets the View to be displayed as the main content view. The method is overloaded, so you can either pass an object of View class (or it's a subclass, such as LinearLayout, TextView, etc.), or you can provide the XML layout resource by using **`R.layout.your_layoutname.xml`**.

Thus, **`R.layout.`** references any layout resource you have created, usually in `/res/layout`. So if you created an activity layout called `activity_main.xml`, you can then use the reference in `R.layout.activity_main` to access it.